# Equation solving with magnitude constraints incredibly slow

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, complex

Somewhat complicated question and sorry in advance if it is presented poorly.  I'm running Mathematica 12.0 (haven't updated to 12.1 yet).  I'm trying to solve a set of linear complex equations with an additional constraint on the magnitudes of the solutions.  What I have tried is very slow, and I'm hoping someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Here is a simplified version of what I tried originally.  The real number $d$ and the odd prime $p$ were defined beforehand.  [Edit: I tried to remove all the complicated formulas from the code, but I've added them back in response to a comment.]

```
p = 3;
d = (p + Sqrt[p^2 + 4*p])/2;
m = 2;
a[n_] := Exp[2*Pi*I*n^2*m/p];
innerProd[g_, h_] := a[g]*a[h]*Conjugate[a[g + h]];
cCubed = 1/Sqrt[p]*Sum[Conjugate[a[g]], {g, 0, p - 1}];
c = cCubed^(1/3);

b[0] = -1/d;
vars = Array[b, p - 1];

equ = {};
For[g = 1, g < p, g++,
 AppendTo[equ, b[g] == Conjugate[c*a[g]]/Sqrt[p]*Sum[innerProd[g, h]*b[h], {h, 0, p - 1}]];
 ]
For[g = 1, g < p, g++,
 AppendTo[equ, Abs[b[g]] == 1/Sqrt[p]];
 ]

Reduce[equ, vars, Complexes]
```

In the case $p=3$, this is a system of two linear equations with two unknowns plus two more equations that specify the magnitude of the solutions.  When I tried to run it, `Reduce` went overnight, used all my memory (16 GB + 32 GB SWAP drive), and did not finish.  I believe `Solve` and `NSolve` similarly fail.

I managed to solve this issue by splitting the problem into two pieces, as below.

```
(* same stuff as before *)

b[0] = -1/d;
vars = Array[b, p - 1];

equ = {};
For[g = 1, g < p, g++,
 AppendTo[equ, b[g] == Conjugate[c*a[g]]/Sqrt[p]*Sum[innerProd[g, h]*b[h], {h, 0, p - 1}]];
 ]

solns = Reduce[equ, vars, Complexes] // Simplify;
equ = {};
AppendTo[equ, solns];

For[g = 1, g < p, g++,
 AppendTo[equ, Abs[b[g]] == 1/Sqrt[p]];
 ]

Reduce[equ, vars, Complexes]
```

What I am doing now is first solving the 2x2 system.  That gives me a vector space of solutions in the form of $b_2 = b_1 + C$.  I am then creating an equation list with that and the magnitude constraints.  This runs very quickly and gives me two unique solutions (which is exactly what I want).  Does anyone know why Mathematica struggles with the original four equation set when it can do them separately just fine?

Moving on to the case $p=5$ (the next easiest case), the first `Reduce` (a linear system of four equations with four unknowns) runs quickly.  The second `Reduce`, which imposes the magnitude constraints runs overnight without finishing.  I had assumed that fixing the magnitudes would not be a difficult part of this computation, so can anyone tell me if I'm doing something horribly wrong?

Just to get out ahead of some possible answers, the next thing I tried was writing each $b_g$ as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{p}}e^{i\theta_g}$ and solving for $\theta_g$ since the magnitudes are known.  This way, the equations are no longer linear.  They are linear in exponential variables.  Still, Mathematica is able to `Reduce` reasonably quickly.  As expected, the answer includes integer constants multiplied by $2\pi$.  Asking Mathematica to solve the solution it just gave with the additional constraint that $0 \leq \theta_g < 2\pi$ for all $g$ again goes overnight without finishing.  I am thorougly flummoxed as I had assumed limiting to $[0,2\pi)$ would be the easy part of this computation.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Finally, I tried rewriting the linear system as a matrix and using linear algebra functions, but things like `LinearSolve` give only one solution, and I am looking for all of them.  Mathematica documentation says the proper function to use for that is `Solve`, which brings me back to the original problems I was having.

Comment: Please provide code that readers can run.  "function linear in b[i] vars" is not adequate.

Comment: Sorry!  I was trying to just ask about the parts I thought were important, but I have added some back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll show something that works quickly on the first example.

First we use `ComplexExpand`, then replace e.g. `Re[b[1]]` with `re[b[1]]` so that it can be treated as a variable (this might not work if we kept the head as `the built-in function` Re`).

```
neweq = ComplexExpand[
    Apply[Subtract, equ, {1}] // Expand,
{b[1], b[2]}] /. {Re -> re, Im -> im};
```

Now separate real and imaginary parts.

```
reeq = ComplexExpand[Re[neweq]];
imeq = ComplexExpand[Im[neweq]];
```

We can now solve for these over the reals.

```
Solve[Join[reeq, imeq] == 0, Reals]

(* Out[161]= {{im[b[1]] -> (1/(
   9 + 3 Sqrt[21]))(-4 Sqrt[3] - 
     9 (1/8 (Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[7]) - 1/8 Sqrt[1/3 (6 + 2 Sqrt[21])]) - 
     3 Sqrt[21] (1/8 (Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[7]) - 
        1/8 Sqrt[1/3 (6 + 2 Sqrt[21])]) - 
     1/2 Sqrt[
      3] (3 - Sqrt[21] - 
        6 Sqrt[3] (1/8 (Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[7]) - 
           1/8 Sqrt[1/3 (6 + 2 Sqrt[21])])) - 
     1/2 Sqrt[
      7] (3 - Sqrt[21] - 
        6 Sqrt[3] (1/8 (Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[7]) - 
           1/8 Sqrt[1/3 (6 + 2 Sqrt[21])])) - 
     1/4 Sqrt[
      3] (-3 + Sqrt[21] + 
        12 Sqrt[3] (1/8 (Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[7]) - 
           1/8 Sqrt[1/3 (6 + 2 Sqrt[21])])) - 
     1/4 Sqrt[
      7] (-3 + Sqrt[21] + 
        12 Sqrt[3] (1/8 (Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[7]) - 
           1/8 Sqrt[1/3 (6 + 2 Sqrt[21])]))), 
  im[b[2]] -> 
   1/8 (Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[7]) - 1/8 Sqrt[1/3 (6 + 2 Sqrt[21])], 
  re[b[1]] -> 
   1/12 (-3 + Sqrt[21] + 
      12 Sqrt[3] (1/8 (Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[7]) - 
         1/8 Sqrt[1/3 (6 + 2 Sqrt[21])])), 
  re[b[2]] -> 
   1/6 (3 - Sqrt[21] - 
      6 Sqrt[3] (1/8 (Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[7]) - 
         1/8 Sqrt[1/3 (6 + 2 Sqrt[21])]))}, {im[b[1]] -> (1/(
   9 + 3 Sqrt[21]))(-4 Sqrt[3] - 
     9 (1/8 (Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[7]) + 1/8 Sqrt[1/3 (6 + 2 Sqrt[21])]) - 
     3 Sqrt[21] (1/8 (Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[7]) + 
        1/8 Sqrt[1/3 (6 + 2 Sqrt[21])]) - 
     1/2 Sqrt[
      3] (3 - Sqrt[21] - 
        6 Sqrt[3] (1/8 (Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[7]) + 
           1/8 Sqrt[1/3 (6 + 2 Sqrt[21])])) - 
     1/2 Sqrt[
      7] (3 - Sqrt[21] - 
        6 Sqrt[3] (1/8 (Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[7]) + 
           1/8 Sqrt[1/3 (6 + 2 Sqrt[21])])) - 
     1/4 Sqrt[
      3] (-3 + Sqrt[21] + 
        12 Sqrt[3] (1/8 (Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[7]) + 
           1/8 Sqrt[1/3 (6 + 2 Sqrt[21])])) - 
     1/4 Sqrt[
      7] (-3 + Sqrt[21] + 
        12 Sqrt[3] (1/8 (Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[7]) + 
           1/8 Sqrt[1/3 (6 + 2 Sqrt[21])]))), 
  im[b[2]] -> 
   1/8 (Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[7]) + 1/8 Sqrt[1/3 (6 + 2 Sqrt[21])], 
  re[b[1]] -> 
   1/12 (-3 + Sqrt[21] + 
      12 Sqrt[3] (1/8 (Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[7]) + 
         1/8 Sqrt[1/3 (6 + 2 Sqrt[21])])), 
  re[b[2]] -> 
   1/6 (3 - Sqrt[21] - 
      6 Sqrt[3] (1/8 (Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[7]) + 
         1/8 Sqrt[1/3 (6 + 2 Sqrt[21])]))}} *)
```

Reconstructing `b[1]` and `b[2]` from this is now straightforward.

--- edit ---

Yes, the case for `p=5` does appear to be much more difficult. I changed some of the setup to effectively remove the explicit `Conjugate` in the resulting equations.

```
p = 5;
d = (p + Sqrt[p^2 + 4*p])/2;
m = 2;
a[n_] := Exp[2*Pi*I*n^2*m/p];
conja[n_] := Exp[-2*Pi*I*n^2*m/p];
innerProd[g_, h_] := a[g]*a[h]*conja[g + h];
cCubed = 1/Sqrt[p]*Sum[conja[g], {g, 0, p - 1}];
c = FullSimplify[cCubed]^(1/3);
b[0] = -1/d;
vars = Array[b, p - 1];
equ = Join[
   Table[-b[g] + 
     Conjugate[c]*conja[g]/Sqrt[p]*
      Sum[innerProd[g, h]*b[h], {h, 0, p - 1}], {g, 1, p - 1}],
   Table[Abs[b[g]]^2 - 1/p, {g, 1, p}]];
```

We can slightly simplify the preprocessing here.

```
neweq = equ /. {b[n_] -> re[b[n]] + I*im[b[n]]};
reeq = ComplexExpand[Re[neweq]];
imeq = ComplexExpand[Im[neweq]];
```

But this next step might still hang.

```
Solve[Join[reeq, imeq] == 0]
```

Further restricing to `Reals` will likely make it slower still...

--- end edit ---

Comment: Thank you!  This is indeed much quicker, and the answer agrees with what I have for $p=3$.  I tried changing $p$ to $5$, and it's having issues.  When I run the line to produce `neweq`, Mathematica complains `Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 50.  Reached while evaluating Im[2e^{-\frac{4i\pi}{5}} + 2e^{\frac{4i\pi}{5}}]`.  I believe this answer should just be zero, though I tried increasing the `MaxExtraPrecision` size to 100,000 just in case.  I now get the same message, but with 100k instead of 50.

Also, the `Solve` line now just returns itself when $p=5$.

Comment: After above edit:

Indeed, ```Solve``` still takes a long time for $p=5$.  I even tried ```Solve```ing the first ```Table``` and adding the solution to the second ```Table```, which helped in my original approach.  I guess this problem is more difficult than expected.

I also tried ```NSolve```.  The first time, it told me there were infinitely many solutions and it would intersect with a particular equation, but then gave no solutions.  I have not been able to replicate that warning.  Since then, it completes but gives an empty set, a result I have reason to be skeptical of.

Comment: After another simplification I can replicate the problem you saw. I'll look more when I get a chance.

Comment: The "infinite solutions" might be a minor bug. I think the real issue is that there are 13 nontrivial equations in 8 unknowns, so the system is over-determined and very possibly just inconsistent.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my last comment, but I also changed the second ```Table``` to go $g=1$ to $p-1$ rather than $p$ since $p = 0$ in mod $p$.  I did not think the system was inconsistent, but perhaps it is.  I will mark the problem as solved for now and look into it some more (outside of Mathematica).  Thank you!

Comment: I'd be curious to hear if you find anything to suggest it is solvable.